# How to create index in BigQuery on a jsonPayload field of a GCP log?

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-logging

I'm exporting my GCP logs to BigQuery to view them better. From [here](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/export/bigquery), it seems like fields in the jsonPayload of my logEntry, would be turned into a jsonPayload. field in the BigQuery table. One of the fields in the jsonPayload is an internal log ID.

Since BigQuery now allows adding [indexes to tables](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/search-intro), I want to add an index on this jsonPayload.logId field in the table for improved query performance. How do I do that? Or should I be only depending on partitioning and/or clustering for better performance?

Comment: You can create [`index`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/search-index#create_a_search_index) for your JSON field, this works for the query performance. But if you are looking for the best performance between these two I would go with partitioning.